# Im having problems to retrieve the data attributes

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to retrieve the data attributes from the cart but it's not working.

I also would like to know if there's a way to shorten the code.

HTML:

```
<div id="product-listing" class="hidden">
  <div>
    <img src="img1.jpg" />
    <div class="description">Lagavulin 16 Year Old</div>
    <button class="add-to-cart"
            data-product-id="1"
            data-product-title="Lagavulin 16 Year Old" data-category="Scotch">
            Add To Cart
    </button>
```

Vanilla js:

```
function onPageLoad(event) {
  var title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerText;
  console.log({
    event_name: "page loaded",
    page_title: title,

  });
}

var photo = document
  .getElementsByClassName("add-to-cart")
  .getAttribute("data-product-id");

for (var i = 0; i < photo.length; i++) {
  photo[i].onclick = function() {
    console.log({
      event_name: "add_to_cart",
      product_id: data-product-id,
      product_title: data-product-title,
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("add-to-cart")).forEach(x => x.onclick = () => console.log({
  event_name: "add_to_cart",
  product_id: x.getAttribute("data-product-id"),
  product_title: x.getAttribute("data-product-title")
}));
```

```html
<button class="add-to-cart" data-product-id="1" data-product-title="Lagavulin 16 Year Old" data-category="Scotch">Add To Cart</button>

<button class="add-to-cart" data-product-id="2" data-product-title="Some other Scotch" data-category="Scotch">Add To Cart</button>
```

You were not properly iterating over the elements returned by `getElementsByClass` and also not using `element.getAttribute("")` correctly.

To make it shorter I used streams.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
var photo = document
  .getElementsByClassName("add-to-cart");

for (var i = 0; i < photo.length; i++) {
  photo[i].onclick = function() {

    console.log({
      event_name: "add_to_cart",
      product_id: photo[i].getAttribute("data-product-id"),
      product_title:  photo[i].getAttribute("data-product-title"),
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var photo = document.querySelectorAll('.add-to-cart');
photo.forEach(function(button){
    button.addEventListener('click',function(){
        console.log(this.getAttribute('data-product-id'));
    },{passive:true});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for loops. [Target the button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and then [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) (note: hyphenated attributes like `data-product-id` will be represented in camelCase in the data set: `productId`, for example), and class name from the button, relabel them, and then assign the values to a new object.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.add-to-cart');
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick() {
  
  const {
    className: event_name,
    dataset: {
      productId: product_id,
      productTitle: product_title
    }
  } = this;
  
  const obj = { event_name, product_id, product_title };
  
  console.log(obj);

}
```

```html
<div id="product-listing" class="hidden">
  <div class="description">Lagavulin 16 Year Old</div>
  <button class="add-to-cart" data-product-id="1" data-product-title="Lagavulin 16 Year Old" data-category="Scotch">Add To Cart</button>
</div>
```